# Sleuth not working for websocket client

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a microservice which is connecting to the WebSocket server, and receiving the messages from the server. I want to integrate Sleuth in this application, as this is the gateway for my set of microservices. But when I connect to the WebSocket server and start receiving messages, I can't traceId, spanid in the log in the log. I was expecting something like:

```
2018-08-09 11:26:20.222  INFO [kumarman-betsync-adapter-service-v2,0a011711c2470359,0a011711c2470359,true] 7230 --- [ient-SecureIO-2] c.b.b.a.service.BetSyncEventIdExtractor  : SubscribeResponse feed received for eventId=7519016
2018-08-09 11:26:20.224  INFO [kumarman-betsync-adapter-service-v2,0a011711c2470359,2b028dadad5c440d,true] 7230 --- [ient-SecureIO-2] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncEventTopic'
```

But I am getting:

```
2018-08-09 11:26:20.222  INFO [kumarman-betsync-adapter-service-v2,,,] 7230 --- [ient-SecureIO-2] c.b.b.a.service.BetSyncEventIdExtractor  : SubscribeResponse feed received for eventId=7519016
2018-08-09 11:26:20.224  INFO [kumarman-betsync-adapter-service-v2,,,] 7230 --- [ient-SecureIO-2] c.b.b.a.k.message.KafkaMessageSender     : sent payload to topic='betsyncEventTopic'
```

my code is as follows:

```
  @Service
    @Slf4j
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class BetsyncWebsocketAdapter {

        private final BetsyncWebSocketHandler betsyncWebSocketHandler;

        public void startNewConnection() {
                try {
                    webSocketSession = new StandardWebSocketClient().doHandshake(
                            betsyncWebSocketHandler,
                            new WebSocketHttpHeaders(),
                            new URI(getBetsyncConnectionUrl()))
                            .get(KafkaAdminClient.MAX_TIME_LIMIT_TO_CONNECT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.error("exception occurred", e);
                }
        }

        /**
         * This will start the new connection after server start
         */
        @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
        public void onServerStart() {
            startNewConnection();
        }
    }

@Slf4j
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BetsyncWebSocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private static StringBuilder betSyncMessage = new StringBuilder();

    private final LoginRequestBuilder loginRequestBuilder;
    private final BetsyncMessageProcessing betsyncMessageProcessing;

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(final WebSocketSession session) throws IOException {
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage(loginRequestBuilder.getLoginRequestDto()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(final WebSocketSession session, final TextMessage message) {
        betSyncMessage.append(message.getPayload());
        if (message.isLast()) {
            betsyncMessageProcessing.process(betSyncMessage.toString());
            betSyncMessage = new StringBuilder();
        } else {
            log.debug("we have received a partial message starting with {}", getFirstXCharacter(message.getPayload(), 50));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void handlePongMessage(final WebSocketSession session, final PongMessage message) {
        log.info("Response for Ping message received from the server");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
        log.error("server connection closed");
    }
}
```

Our pom entries are:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
        <spring.boot.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
```

Comment: Can you read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide any useful information regarding your problems?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I have updated the ticket now.

Comment: Still i have no idea which version of sleuth you're using, how you've added it to the project. Also we support websockets via spring integration. I don't see it here

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I have added the pom.xml. There is no other code related to WebSocket, I can see in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the socket handling by yourself

```
 webSocketSession = new StandardWebSocketClient().doHandshake(
                            betsyncWebSocketHandler,
                            new WebSocketHttpHeaders(),
                            new URI(getBetsyncConnectionUrl()))
                            .get(KafkaAdminClient.MAX_TIME_LIMIT_TO_CONNECT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Spring Cloud Sleuth supports WebSockets, when you use Spring Integration components directly. Since you're doing things manually, you have to ensure that the tracing context gets propagated and that you can read it yourself.

Comment: Hi Marcin, when I use @NewSpan, I can start seeing the log as expected, which I added in my question and it has different traceId fro each received message, but after few hours of running, I can see all the messages starting using the same traceId. I am not sure how? How you have some idea or I will have to get more detail?

Comment: Definitely, more detail is required. I have no idea where you put the `@NewSpan`.  Can you create a small, reproducible sample and upload it to Github?

Comment: Hi Marcin, I have created a sample project in https://github.com/krmanish007/SleuthtestApplication

Comment: Can you actually file an issue in Sleuth project? I don't want to forget about this.

Comment: Sure Marcin, I have created it here at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1058